# C++ Hangman game using Hashing/Collision Algorithm

Tags: c++

I have a school project to create a hangman game using Hashing and Collision algorithm.
This is the code created so far but it doesn't include Hashing. We're a group project so 2 different codes were created so far. I need to ass a Hashing Algorithm and I don't know-how to.
this is the Assignment.
For this assignment, you will be making a simple version of the Hangman Word Guessing game with. This game will be played in the terminal window. In this game, the computer picks a random word from a pre-supplied list (from a text file). The rules are same as the classic hangman game which are
i.  The player tries to solve to puzzle by guessing one letter at a time.
ii. Every time a guess is correct, all the characters in the word that match the guess will be `turned over.'' For example, if your guess is` o'' and the word is `book'', then both` o''s in the solution will be counted as ``solved.''
iii.    Every time a wrong guess is made, a stroke will be added to the drawing of a hangman, which needs 7 strokes to complete (Figure 1). Each unique wrong guess only counts against the player once.
iv. If the drawing of the hangman is completed before the player has successfully guessed all the characters of the word, the player loses.
v.  If the player has guessed all the characters of the word before the drawing is complete, the player wins the game.
vi. If the player does not guess enough letters to either win or lose, then display appropriate message.

Figure 1

On top of that, your game also need to keep track of previously guessed letters and tell the user. The application also able to record and retrieve the players’ game history’s such as how many time the player win, lose or draw; how many attempts the player won the game or any other information. Make sure your game runs until the player decides to quit and must be user friendly.

Other than array and function, Hash Function and Collision Resolution must be used to develop the Hangman Word Guessing game. Also, can use any other algorithm(s) to make the game more efficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    char start{};

    std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   | /|\\" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   | / \\" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Press any key (and Enter) to start" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> start;

    int Tries{7};
    char Guess;
    bool CorrectGuess = false;
    char PreviousGuesses[7];
    PreviousGuesses[0] = '\0';
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        PreviousGuesses[i] = '-';
    }
    PreviousGuesses[6] = '\0';
    std::string Word;
    std::string WordList[99];

    srand(time(NULL));
    std::ifstream RandomWord;
    RandomWord.open("assignment.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        RandomWord >> WordList[i];
        std::cout << WordList[i] << std::endl;
    }
    int RandomNum = rand() % 100;
    Word = WordList(RandomNum);
    std::cout << Word << std::endl;
    RandomWord.close();

    std::string MysteryWord(Word.length(), '*');

    while (Tries >= 0)
    {
        CorrectGuess = false;

        std::cout << "The word you have to is :\n\n";
        std::cout << MysteryWord << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\nThere are " << MysteryWord.length << "letters in the word\n\n";
        std::cout << "You have " << Tries << "guesses left\n";
        if (PreviousGuesses == '\0')
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::"You have guessed: " << PreviousGuesses << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "\nGuess a letter: ";
        std::cin >> Guess;

        for (int i = 0; i < MysteryWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (Word[i] == Guess)
            {
                MysteryWord[i] = Guess;
                CorrectGuess = True;
            }
        }
        if (Word == MysteryWord)
        {
            std::cout << "\n\nCongratulations! you've got the word correct:  " << MysteryWord << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (CorrectGuess == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, " << Guess << "is not part of the word" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Congratulation! " << Guess << "is one of the letters! " << std::endl;
        }

        switch (Tries)
        {
        case 7:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[0] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 6:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[1] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[2] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[3] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | /|" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[4] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | /|\\" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[5] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | /|\\" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | / " << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[6] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 0:
        {
            std::cout << "_____" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  O" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | /|\\" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   |  |" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "   | / \\" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " __|_" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |   |______" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " |_________|" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\n\nGAME OVER" << std::endl;
            Tries--;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[7] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            std::cout << "--Error--";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to use a hash would be instead of PreviousGuesses (which is WAY too short, by the way), you could use:

```
#include <map>

std::map<char, bool> previousGuesses;
```

You can then populate previousGuesses with each letter and "false" indicating they haven't already tried that letter. You would need to learn about std::map. There are tutorials about it.

Alternatively, I believe std::set also uses a hash.

```
#include <set>

std::set<char> previousGuesses;
```

You would need to read about std::set.

Either approach will take you a little time. If I were doing it, maybe 5 minutes, but as you haven't done this before, maybe an hour or so. You might want to write a little sample program that works with the map/set (as you pick) so you understand how to add to them and check to see if the person already guessed, and I suppose to write out what the previous guesses were.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "    HANGMAN" << endl;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "   |  |" << endl;
    cout << "   |  O" << endl;
    cout << "   | /|\\" << endl;
    cout << "   |  |" << endl;
    cout << "   | / \\" << endl;
    cout << " __|_" << endl;
    cout << " |   |______" << endl;
    cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
    cout << " Press [Enter] to start playing" << endl;

    while(true)
    {
        if (getchar() == '\n')
        {
            cout << " -----------------------------" << endl << endl; 
            break;
        }
    }

    int Tries = 7;
    bool CorrectGuess = false;
    bool Duplicate = false;
    char Guess;
    char PreviousGuesses[6];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        PreviousGuesses[i] = '-';
    }

    string Word;
    string WordList[99];
    srand(time(NULL));
    ifstream RandomWord;
    //RandomWord.open("assignment.txt");
    //for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    //{
    //    RandomWord >> WordList[i];
    //    cout << WordList[i] << endl;
    //}
    //int RandomNum = rand() % 100;
    //Word = WordList[RandomNum];
    Word = "pineapple";
    //cout << Word << endl;
    //RandomWord.close();

    string MysteryWord(Word.length(), '*');

    cout << " There are " << MysteryWord.length() << " letters in the word." << endl << endl;
    cout << " -----------------------------" << endl << endl; 

    while (Tries > 0)
    {
        CorrectGuess = false;

        cout << " Letters found:" << endl << endl;
        cout << " " << MysteryWord << endl << endl;
        cout << " You have " << Tries << " chances left." << endl << endl;
        cout << " You have made the following wrong guesses: " << PreviousGuesses << endl << endl;
        cout << " Guess a letter: ";
        cin >> Guess;

        for (int i = 0; i < MysteryWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (Word[i] == Guess)
            {
                if(MysteryWord[i] != Guess)
                {
                    MysteryWord[i] = Guess;
                    CorrectGuess = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Duplicate = true;
                    CorrectGuess = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Word == MysteryWord)
        {
            cout << "\n\n Congratulations! you've got the word correct:  " << MysteryWord << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (CorrectGuess == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                if(PreviousGuesses[i] == Guess)
                {
                    cout << "\n You already guessed that letter." << endl << endl;
                    cout << " -----------------------------" << endl; 
                    Duplicate = true;
                }
            }
            if(!Duplicate)
            {
                cout << "\n Sorry, " << Guess << " is not part of the word!" << endl << endl;
                cout << " -----------------------------" << endl; 
                Tries--;
                Duplicate = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Duplicate)
            {
                cout << "\n " << Guess << " is one of the letters! " << endl << endl;
                cout << " -----------------------------" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\n You already guessed that letter." << endl << endl;
                cout << " -----------------------------" << endl;
                Duplicate = false;
            }
        }

        switch (Tries)
        {
        case 7:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  " << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << "   |  " << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 6:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << "   |  " << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[0] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  " << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[1] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl; 
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[2] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   | /|" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[3] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   | /|\\" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   | " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl; 
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[4] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   | /|\\" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   | / " << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            if (CorrectGuess == false)
            {
                PreviousGuesses[5] = Guess;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 0:
        {
            cout << "_______" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   |  O" << endl;
            cout << "   | /|\\" << endl;
            cout << "   |  |" << endl;
            cout << "   | / \\" << endl;
            cout << " __|_" << endl;
            cout << " |   |______" << endl;
            cout << " |_________|" << endl << endl;
            cout << " GAME OVER" << endl;
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "--Error--";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```